# Search for a node in react-d3-graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, d3.js, react-d3-graph

How to search for a particular node in react-d3-graph.Are there any inbuilt api methods or can we achieve this using just react.
https://danielcaldas.github.io/react-d3-graph/docs/

Comment: to try to search in data.nodes by id

Comment: yes but how to do it? @romanown

Comment: is any solution found @Sam